# Data from array to sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array that plots data to a messagebox, how can I also have that same data on a different sheet?

The data I am working with is a linear cable cut list. It looks at the total cable length and the individual lengths and checks to see how many reels of cable I need for all the separate individual lengths.

Ideally Reel 1 lengths would go in column A and the next reel would be column B, so on and so forth with a blank column in between the different cable types.

```
    'Message Box Output
    For k = LBound(DetStk, 2) To UBound(DetStk, 2)
       sMsg = sMsg & DetStk(1, k) & vbTab & vbTab _
            & DetStk(0, k) & vbCrLf
    Next k
```

THIS IS WHAT I GOT WORKING WITH HELP FROM "Splintered-Origins-Dev"

```
    'Sheet Output
    n = 3
    q = rC + p - 6
    For k = LBound(DetStk, 2) To UBound(DetStk, 2)
        If k - 1 >= LBound(DetStk, 2) Then
            If DetStk(0, k - 1) <> DetStk(0, k) Then
                'Data line reset
                n = 3
                p = p + 1
                q = rC + p - 6
                wsVG.Cells(1, q).Value2 = cblType
                wsVG.Cells(2, q).Value2 = DetStk(0, k) & " Reels"
            End If
        Else
            wsVG.Cells(1, q).Value2 = cblType
            wsVG.Cells(2, q).Value2 = DetStk(0, k) & " Reels"
        End If
        wsVG.Cells(n, q).Value2 = DetStk(1, k)
        n = n + 1
    Next k
```

Comment: We don't need the entire code, we need a [reprex]... emphasis on the "minimal" :-)

Comment: @BigBen the first set of code is just for populating the msgbox with data. Second set is how its getting the data.

Comment: Right... but those are tangential to your main question, which is how to get transfer data from the array to the sheet... Can you cut your question down to how you tried that?

Comment: @BigBen its the commented out portion at the end of the first code set.

Comment: Then please remove everything else, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty or elegant, but the following code will allow you to output the data going to your message box to a new sheet "Reel Data". Just replace "*loopvar*" with whatever variable you're using to iterate through each loop. Additionally the "- 1" in the q variable for columns may or may not be needed depending on how your loop variable is set up. I also recommend adding someplace at the beginning of the sub *Worksheets("Reel Data").Cells.Clear* to wipe out any old data left behind by previous runs and *p = 0* to reset the column counter.

```
    n = 3 'Row
    q = *loopvar* + p - 1 'Column
    For k = LBound(DetStk, 2) To UBound(DetStk, 2)
        If k - 1 >= LBound(DetStk, 2) Then 'If reel count changes, move over a column
            If DetStk(0, k - 1) <> DetStk(0, k) Then
                n = 3 'Row reset
                p = p + 1 'Increment Column
                q = *loopvar* + p - 1
                Worksheets("Reel Data").Cells(2, q).Value2 = DetStk(0, k)
            End If
        Else
            Worksheets("Reel Data").Cells(2, q).Value2 = DetStk(0, k) 'First Reel
        End If
        Worksheets("Reel Data").Cells(n, q).Value2 = DetStk(1, k)
        n = n + 1 ' Increment Row
    Next k
    p = p + 1 'This will add an extra column before the next iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

DetStk Array's  2 rows an k colunms .  so You should switch the matrix to make it easier to see.

From

```
'Message Box Output
For k = LBound(DetStk, 2) To UBound(DetStk, 2)
   sMsg = sMsg & DetStk(1, k) & vbTab & vbTab _
        & DetStk(0, k) & vbCrLf
Next k
```

to

```
'Sheet Output
Sheets.Add
Range("a1").Resize(UBound(DetStk, 2) + 1, UBound(DetStk, 1) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(DetStk)
```